# RGB values under the mouse cursor

Tags: java, rgb

Using these classes :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

How can i get my program to read the rgb values under my mouse while i hover over the screen and have a Jframe display the color itself. the rgb values. and possibly the name of the color

Comment: by screen do you mean the entire screen or part of your application?

Comment: are you trying to do some color chooser? if so, take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html

Comment: Vandale I mean like my desktop anything my mouse hovers over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package stack;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class TheColorInfo {
    static PointerInfo pointer;
    static Point point;
    static Robot robot;

    static Color color;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            robot = new Robot();

            while(true){
                pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                point = pointer.getLocation();
                if(point.getX() == 0 && point.getY() == 0){
                    break; // stop the program when you go to (0,0)
                }else{
                    color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(),(int)point.getY());
                    System.out.println("Color at: " + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + " is: " + color);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

The SSCCE above shows how you can go about getting the color of any pixel on the screen using the `Robot` class.

Since the return type of `getPixelColor()` is `java.awt.Color`, you can extract the red, green and blue values of the pixel. I have left adding the GUI to you.

Comment: Code error says reached end of file while parsing. What does that mean ?

Comment: @user2950612 It means you didn't copy all the code, so you are missing an ending bracket.

Comment: thank you if i add my code can you help me put it in the jframe and then put the color in the jframe ?

Comment: yeah sadly i am :/ i'm a beginner.